# Как считать данные из файла csv, если не знаешь какой разделитель?

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть файл с данными, но я не знаю какой там разделитель(кстати какие бывают разделители, я знаю про "," ";"), как считать данные ? Считываю при помощи pandas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

чтобы определить разделитель используйте ***csv.Sniffer***

```
import csv


def find_delimiter(path):
    sniffer = csv.Sniffer()
    with open(path) as fp:
        delimiter = sniffer.sniff(fp.read(5000)).delimiter
    return delimiter
```

Небольшие пояснения:

`fp.read(5000)` - указывается размер буфера, чтобы не читать весь файл. В данной случае 5000 байт, потому что этого достаточно, чтобы определить разделитель.

```
>>> find_delimiter('your_path_to_file/file.csv')
';'
```

[оригинал ответа - SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69817138/13696722)